# Different return types, overloading __add__

Tags: python, addition, magic-methods

I wish to implement something like the following. There is a class `foo` which contains a list of `infoo` objects. I was thinking that in order to overload the `__add__` operator I should

```
class foo(object):
    def __init__(self, infoo_list):
        self.args = infoo_list

    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, type(self)):
            newargs = self.args + other.args
            return foo(newargs)
        elif isinstance(other, infoo_type):
            newargs = self.args + [other]
            return foo(newargs)


class infoo (object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __add__(self, other):
        return foo([self, other])


infoo_type = type(infoo())
```

As you may see `foo` is a container of `infoo` objects. You may have an `infoo` object alone in the universe and operate on it. But, no matter what, if you have to manage more than one, the `foo` object comes into play.

Even though the user could instantiate an `infoo` object to play, the code is oriented towards letting the interface of `foo` handle whenever there are more than one `infoo`.

Is this good practice? Am I breaking some golden rule?

Comment: Personally I wouldn't put code in an element class that tries to magically switch itself out for a container class. It's not expected behaviour. Right now I can't think of a single time I've seen this or would have wanted this to happen. Your interface should do things the least surprising way or you're setting yourself up for confusion and frustrating debugging in the future.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Kemp for your answer. The fact is that it does not make any sense to add the infoo objects without getting the container. There is no other way of interpreting the add operator in this class, rather than creating the container, no merging arguments, no operations between arguements. The foo class actually is constellation, and the infoo class is satellite. You can create a satellite and play, but when you add two of them, it becomes a constellation. Constellation is a container with steroids, to do some transformations.

Comment: You are building a non commutative additive operator. If `f` is a `foo` instance and `i` and `infoo` instance, `f + i` will be a `foo` but `i + f` would be a syntax error. If `foo` is going to be a container of `infoo` why not derive it from the abstract classes from `collections.abc`?

Comment: @ivanculet Why implement the add operator at all if it doesn't make sense? You're not required to give every class every possible operator.

Comment: Thanks a lot @SergeBallesta for the remark. I will look into that. I am building this as my first big project besides scripting thingies, this type of commentaries are invaluable! Thanks again.

Comment: @Kemp True!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially covered in the comments, but something like this would be a cleaner design:

```
class InFoo:
    pass

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, infoos):
        self.args = list(infoos)

    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, __class__):
            oargs = other.args
        elif isinstance(other, InFoo):
            oargs = [other]
        return foo(self.args + oargs)
```

There does not appear to be any good reason to define `__add__` on `InFoo`, since addition is only meaningful for containers in this case. This also eliminates the need to externally define `infoo_type`. Python convention is to make class names CamelCase and pretty much everything else snake_case.